# Net Core WCF error "One or more errors occurred. (There was no endpoint listening at"

Tags: .net, wcf, iis, soap, service

I am calling an external soap service. In development it works fine, but publishing it on the server throws the indicated error.

"One or more errors occurred. (There was no endpoint listening at that https://myservice could accept the message. This is often caused by an incorrect address or SOAP action. See InnerException, if present, for more details.)"

If I refresh the page the error changes:

An unhandled exception occurred while processing the request.
AggregateException: One or more errors occurred. (Object is read-only.)
System.Threading.Tasks.Task.GetResultCore(bool waitCompletionNotification)

InvalidOperationException: Object is read-only.
System.ServiceModel.Security.X509CertificateRecipientClientCredential.ThrowIfImmutable()

This is the code:

```
            PortTypeClient.ClientCredentials.ServiceCertificate.SslCertificateAuthentication= new X509ServiceCertificateAuthentication()
            {
                CertificateValidationMode = X509CertificateValidationMode.None,
                RevocationMode = X509RevocationMode.NoCheck
            };
```

Answer (score 0):

According to the error message  `"One or more errors occurred. (There was no endpoint listening at that https://myservice could accept the message. This is often caused by an incorrect address or SOAP action. See InnerException, if present, for more details.)"`, it seems that you do not define a binding in your service's config, so you are getting the default values for wsHttpBinding, and the default value for securityMode\transport for that binding is Message.

You should  open "Web.config" in the application directory and add the following configuration code into the file. At runtime, the WCF infrastructure uses the information to construct an endpoint that client applications can communicate with.

Config:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8" ?>
<configuration>
  <system.serviceModel>
    <services>
      <service name="Microsoft.ServiceModel.Samples.CalculatorService">

        <!-- This endpoint is exposed at the base address provided by host: http://localhost/servicemodelsamples/service.svc -->
        <endpoint address=""
                  binding="wsHttpBinding"
                  contract="Microsoft.ServiceModel.Samples.ICalculator" />

        <!-- The mex endpoint is explosed at http://localhost/servicemodelsamples/service.svc/mex -->
        <endpoint address="mex"
                  binding="mexHttpBinding"
                  contract="IMetadataExchange" />
      </service>
    </services>
  </system.serviceModel>

</configuration>
```

More details about how to host the wcf application on the IIS, you could refer to this [article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/wcf/feature-details/how-to-host-a-wcf-service-in-iis).